# Extract hashtags from complex string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, hashtag

I have a crazy string, something like:

```
sun #plants #!wood% ##arebaba#tey   travel#blessed    #weed das#$#F!@D!AAAA
```

I want to extract all "words" (also containing special characters) that begin with # or that have a space right before, taking the following as a result:

```
[
  'sun',
  'plants',
  '!wood%',
  'arebaba',
  'tey',
  'travel',
  'blessed',
  'weed',
  'das',
  '$',
  'F!@D!AAAA'
]
```

How do I get this using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` using regex: `[^#\s]+`:

```js
var str = 'sun #plants #!wood% ##arebaba#tey   travel#blessed    #weed das#$#F!@D!AAAA';
    
var arr = str.match(/[^\s#]+/g);

console.log(arr);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wXIMo7/6)

Comment: There's only one problem, it´s matching spaces if the string is just spaces, like "       ". Should return an empty array [].

Comment: Can you clarify, how is that related to your question title of `Extract hashtags from complex string using regex`?

Comment: For example, if the user type only some spaces in the input and I match the hashtags he typed using using your regex, it will not return an empty array, since the user does not typed any hashtag. In this case should return [].

Comment: @IbnClaudius - If you require a hashtag _or_ space to validate the input, just test it for `[ #][^ #]|[^ #][ #]` ahead of time, then get the array with `[^ #]+`

Answer (score 0):

Just using match you could get all the group 1 matches into an array.

`(?:^|[ #]+)([^ #]+)(?=[ #]|$)`

Easy!

```
 (?: ^ | [ #]+ )
 ( [^ #]+ )                    # (1)
 (?= [ #] | $ )
```

Or, if you feel it's this simple, then just use `([^ #]+)` or  `[^ #]+`
which gets the same thing (like *split* in reverse).