# Array of hashtags used

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to complete this exercise, returning an array with the hashtags used, but I'm only able to return "#" instead of the whole str[i].
What am I doing wrong?

This is my code so far:

```
function extractHashtags(str) {

  let solution = [];
  for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str[i].startsWith('#')){
      solution.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
return solution;
}

    AssertionError: expected [ '#' ] to deeply equal [ '#yolo' ]
          + expected - actual

           [
          -  "#"
          +  "#yolo"
           ]
```

Trying to find out how to do it, came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398984/extract-hashtags-from-complex-string-using-regex) and I've also tried it this way:

```
function extractHashtags(str) {

  let solution = []; 
  solution.push(str.match(/[^#]/g));
  return solution;
}
```

But still doesn't work. I suppose the most elegant way is using regex, but I'm more than lost with it.
Anyone can give me a hand?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49459388/edit) to add the code that is *calling* `extractHashtags`?

Comment: Use `s.match(/#\w+/g)` or `s.match(/\B#\w+/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

`solution.push(str[i]);`

You're only pushing the initial `'#'` character - you want to push the whole word. Assuming tags are separated by spaces, you can try something like this instead:

`const solution = str.split(' ').filter(word => word.startsWith('#'));`

Comment: Thank you, sorted now. I used split like an hour ago, obviously not properly, and dropped it thinking it wasn't the right approach.

Comment: @VisualXZ: To be more flexible, if for example an hashtag is followed by something that isn't a space (a comma or any other "special" character), you can change the split parameter to a regex pattern: `str.split(/[^\w#]+/)` *(all that isn't a word character or a #)*